# Python opening application (.exe) with .lbr

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

When I open an application with python it loads up the window

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\Omnis7\Omnis7.exe"])
```

but doesn't give me the login page. The absolute path in properties is "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\Omnis7\Omnis7.exe" imis4.lbr /m. when I change the path it gives me an error:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\Omnis7\Omnis7.exe" imis4.lbr /m])
```

Can someone please help me to figure out how to execute this?

Comment: You need to pass all your arguments as strings: `subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\Omnis7\Omnis7.exe", "imis4.lbr", "/m"])`

Comment: Although @zondo already posted a solution, you should include "an error" in future posts to help people help you (see: [ask]).

Comment: @Christian sorry for that. I will remember that in future.

Comment: @zondo thanks for the quick response. This time it opened the application but didn't call library(.lbr), just gives me the blank screen, no errors. I have to click File>Open Library and specify the library (imis4.lbr).

Comment: You need to make sure to run the Python script from the same folder as the `.lbr`, or specify the absolute path of that too. (At least, I think so. I don't know much about Windows, so I'm only assuming that imis4.lbr is a file)

Comment: That's what I did: import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\Omnis7\Omnis7.exe", "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASI\iMIS0\IMIS4.LBR"])